# React native Flexbox center ignoring previous item

Tags: flexbox, react-native

I'm creating a custom "Navigation bar" for my app and I need the following layout:

```
| ================================== |
| ICON  TWO LINES TEXT              |    
|       TWO LINES TEXT              |
| ================================== |
```

The two `<Text>` fields should be at the center of the status bar and the icon on the right

That's how it looks like now:

[Current layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D50cU.png)

and in the inspector its how it looks

[View inspector](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SWFQV.png)

as you can see the text is at the center of his space, but I want to be at the center of the entire component.

That's the code right now:

```
const styles = {
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    flexDirection: 'row',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#64619b',
    height: 64,
    paddingTop: 10,
  },
  title: {
    color: 'white',
    fontSize: 17,
  },
  belowTitle: {
    color: 'white',
    fontSize: 20,
    fontWeight: 'bold',
  },
  backButton: {
    width: 32,
    height: 32,
    alignSelf: 'center',
    marginLeft: 16,
  },
  textContainer: {
    flex: 1,
    flexDirection: 'column',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
};

class NavigatorHeader extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return <View style={[styles.container, this.props.style]}>
      <TouchableOpacity onPress={this.onBackPress.bind(this)}>
        <Icon name="ion|ios-arrow-back" size={32} color="white" style={styles.backButton} />
      </TouchableOpacity>
      <View style={styles.textContainer}>
        <Text style={styles.title}>{this.props.title}</Text>
        {this.props.belowTitle && <Text style={styles.belowTitle}>{this.props.belowTitle}</Text>}
      </View>
    </View>;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could handle this by making it three views across. Put you button in the left, text in the center and then leave the right one empty. Then do "flex: 0.25" for the left and right then put "flex: 0.5" for the center. You can of course increase or decrease the two sides just make sure the center is whatever is left to get to 1.0

Comment: Using three views I have the effect I want. Thanks!